# Name 'Lassalle' is not declared

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I am getting following errors while trying to build a solution, which are probably due to missing or corrupt `Lassalle.Flow` DLL files. My question is how can I reinstall or repair this `.dll` does this file comes with .Net installation so that reinstalling the framework would solve it?

Or is there a way I can download the `.dll` and replace it in my `system32` folder? I am using windows XP.

```
Error   652 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.AddFlow' is not defined.    
Error   653 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.Layout.Hierarchic.HFlow' is not defined.
Error   654 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.Arrow' is not defined.
Error   655 Name 'Lassalle' is not declared.
Error   656 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.Line' is not defined.
Error   657 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.AddFlow' is not defined.
Error   658 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.Layout.Hierarchic.HFlow' is not defined.
Error   661 Type 'Node' is not defined.
Error   662 Type 'Lassalle.Flow.Link' is not defined.
Error   663 Name 'Lassalle' is not declared.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those DLLs are not part of the .NET Framework, so repairing or re-installing the .NET Framework will not solve this problem. These DLLs are from a third party called [Lassalle Technologies](http://www.lassalle.com/)

Verify in your Visual Studio project's `References` folder that the path to these DLLs is correct. There will be a red exclamation point or yellow triangle next to the DLL if there is an issue with it.